# Api external with wordpress

Tags: plugins, php, functions, jquery, api

I want to ask a question, and know if you can help me with some example or a function that allows me to do the following.

I have an `API` made on another platform, I want to show what's in that api in wordpress, as follows.

A page of wordpress, should contain a form, with several inputs, when you click in `SEARCH NOW`, must show the results in another page (which was consulted to the api extenal), when clicking on a result, you must take to another page where show the details of that query.

I can do all the queries, but I do not know how to make the results show, because wordpress needs to create each page

pages created in wordpress **`( search, search_results, details)`**

Answer (score 1):

WordPress itself can communicate with external API's through `wp_remote_get` and `wp_remote_post`. See the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get).

In your case, you could create a page template called page-search.php (keep in mind that search.php is reserved for the internal WordPress search functionality, so you would define it as a template, and select it when creating the page), and run your `wp_remote_get` code in that template.

There are of course other ways of doing it, like utilizing Javascript, with or without any of its available libraries.

The [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) makes it quite easy to do it with Javascript.